# Is there a term I can use to refer to this quote from a poem?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a biography. The woman I am writing about lost her father to suicide when she was 14. She later quoted a poem that she said embodied her understanding of his wish for her to "make harbour" in his name. The quote:

> A shipwrecked sailor buried on this coast,
> Bids you set sail.
> Full many a gallant ship
> When we were lost,
> Weathered the gale.

(It is a translated quote from an unknown Greek poet which she may have read in *Pragmatism* by William James.)

Is there a word I can use to refer to the quote? It was her guiding light, so, rather than just refer to it as a "quotation" or "poetry fragment", I'd prefer a word or a term that is more specific if there is one.

> Those few lines were her _______.

Comment: With various shades of meaning: motto, maxim, adage, burthen, mainstay (interesting maybe, as its origin was nautical), lodestone, lodestar, pole star, lux benigna (or 'kindly light', from the hymn), inspiration, linchpin, dictum, axiom, golden rule, tenet.

Comment: I think you need to change the fill-in-the-blank to better match what you're asking for—a more situationally meaningful word for *quotation* or *poetry fragment*. Surely you wouldn't say *Those few lines were her quotation* or *Those few lines were her poetry fragment*. (But if you really do want to complete *Those few lines were her ____*, *guiding light* works just fine and offers a mariner metaphor. *North star* would work. *Lighthouse*...

Answer (score 2):

The term **mantra** is a possibility.

From [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/mantra#:%7E:text=A%20mantra%20is%20a%20motivating,a%20word%20repeated%20in%20meditation.)

> *mantra*
>
> A mantra is a motivating chant, like the “I think I can, I think I
> can” you repeat over and over to yourself on the last stretch of every
> marathon you run.
>
> A mantra is usually any repeated word or phrase, but it can also refer
> more specifically to a word repeated in meditation.

The broadened usage, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantra), includes

> *Definition* There is no generally accepted definition of mantra.
>
> - Renou has defined mantra as a thought ...

The religious overtone may not be exactly what is required.

Comment: *It was her guiding light,* -> **This was her philosophy**: - tends to indicate a good intellect and confidence -- **This embodied her approach to life** - this tends to be used as an objective observation --**This was her doctrine** - tends to indicate that she was somewhat inflexible or very serious in this -- **This described her outlook on life** - less formal, indicates an independence and is rather positive.

Comment: Reply to comments--I like mantra, but I agree I don't want a religious connotation. I will think about these other ideas. None are quite what I meant, I think, but I appreciate the tries!

Comment: In Christian circles, the term 'life verse' is used with the meaning a verse (/ a few connected verses) which you believe God is highlighting especially as personal revelation / encouragement / guidance. One wag (at the time not a Christian) (and not me) had come prepared to answer, if asked what his was, with 'At Parbar westward, four at the causeway, and two at Parbar' [AV; I Chron 26:18].

Comment: Thank you all. I will think on this and figure out what to do. Whoever said I may not want to just have a "fill-in-the-blank" word is correct. You have widened my thinking about this question! My subject was a Unitarian, and not much into the Bible at the time she revealed this poem, nor am I, but I very much appreciate knowing about "life verses." I think this was a verse that guided her life, though not a Biblical one.